# What is GST revenue?

Tags: terminology, gst

I know that Revenue means Income-Investment. However in the context what is meant by revenue here? I do not think there is any investment involved when you take a tax. I feel this is extremely confusing as a topic.

Comment: do you mean taxable income from sales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that Revenue means Income-Investment.

Revenue means income.  A person has income. Companies have income. A government has income.

Income can come from labor. Income can come from selling something. Income can come from collecting user fees, or from collecting taxes.  You can also get revenue from investments. It can be in the form of dividends, interest, or capital gains.

> What is GST revenue?

> However in the context what is meant by revenue here?

GST is a tax. The money collected is revenue for the government.

> I do not think there is any investment involved when you take a tax.

Any investment by the government takes place after the taxes are collected. Do they spend the money now? Or do they use it to improve infrastructure which can lead to more income later?

Answer (score 2):

"GST revenue" is the amount of money collected by the government from [GST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goods_and_Services_Tax_(India)).

http://gstcouncil.gov.in/gst-revenue